# tricky stack or column centered with space between layout in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have two contents lets say they are sized boxes with some height, I am gonna call them ContentA and ContentB. I can make them align to end with a space between them using a Column:

```dart
Column(
 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
 children: [
  ContentA(),
  SizedBox(height: 10),
  ContentB(),
 ],
)
```

But on some screens (big ones), these values leave the ContentA too much to the bottom. Then I centered ContentA and left ContentB on the bottom with a Stack:

```dart
Stack(
 children: [
  Column(
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
   children: [
    ContentA(),
   ],
  ),
  Positioned(
   left: 0, 
   bottom: 0, 
   right: 0, 
   child: ContentB(),
  ),
 ],
)
```

But then on smaller screens this configuration does not leave space between ContentA and ContentB (ContentB has to be in the bottom limit).

The question is: how to make ContentA as much centered as possible, while also leaving at least some space between it and ContentB?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Expanded` and `Flexible` widgets inside the column without any `Stack` like this:

```
Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.red,)),
          Flexible(flex:0,child: SizedBox(height: 10)),
          Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.blue,)),
        ],

    );
```

Comment: Remove the Expanded from the first Container if you don't want.

Comment: it does not work for me, I want both contents to keep their height, and I want the ContentA to be centered in all the space that the column is using, not centered on the remaining top part

Comment: Could you send me a sketch?